# Añadir los registros de 3 campos desde otra tabla, teniendo ambas en común un campo

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo que insertar en una tabla tres registros de otra tabla en campos ya creados, pero debo de hacerlo teniendo en cuenta que ambas comparten un campo y unicamente debo de rellenar los registros de la primera tabla en que el campo de ambas tablas coinciden.

He probado con un insert into, peo al no poder especificar el campo de union, unicamente me crea un nuevo registro

```
INSERT INTO ej6.illes_censals (secce_cd, distr_cd, barri_cd)
SELECT a.secce_cd, a.distr_cd, a.barri_cd
FROM ej6.illes a
```

Comment: Cual es el campo en comun?

Comment: El campo en comun es ilcen_cd

Comment: Pero, si he entendido bien, lo que quieres hacer entonces no es insertar los registros, sino actualizar los que ya existen ¿no? Es decir, quieres hacer un UPDATE y no un INSERT.

Comment: Se podría decir que si, ya que los registros existentes son nulos ahora mismo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo que buscas es actualizar los registros de `illes_censals` que el campo `ilcen_cd` exista también en la tabla `illes`.

```
UPDATE illes_censals SET secce_cd = i.secce_cd, distr_cd = i.distr_cd, barri_cd = i.barri_cd
FROM illes_censals c INNER JOIN illes i
on c.ilcen_cd = i.ilcen_cd
```

Ahora bien, varias consideraciones:

1. Como siempre que hagas un UPDATE **asegúrate a la perfección antes de ejecutarlo, que vas a actualizar los registros que de verdad quieres actualizar**. Para ello yo suelo ejecutar la select correspondiente y veo lo que va a actualizar:

   `SELECT c.*  FROM illes_censals c INNER JOIN illes i on c.ilcen_cd = i.ilcen_cd`
2. Posiblemente tengas que poner algunos filtros en la cláusula WHERE, como `WHERE secce_cd IS NULL AND distr_cd IS NULL AND barri_cd IS NULL` o algo similar.
3. Por último, estoy dando por hecho que quieres hacer un UPDATE de registros que ya existen y actualizar esos tres campos, pero en tu pregunta la verdad es que no lo dejas muy claro (incluso hablas de hacer INSERT). Si esto que yo estoy contestando no es lo que has preguntado, lógicamente, no ejecutes el UPDATE.

Comment: Al utilizar el codigo que me dijiste, se me actualizaba correctamente, pero los valores eran incorrectos. Lo he acabado solucionando de la siguiente forma: UPDATE ej6.illes_censals c SET secce_cd = (SELECT secce_cd FROM ej6.illes i WHERE c.ilcen_cd = i.ilcen_cd);
UPDATE ej6.illes_censals c SET distr_cd = (SELECT distr_cd FROM ej6.illes i WHERE c.ilcen_cd = i.ilcen_cd);
UPDATE ej6.illes_censals c SET barri_cd = (SELECT barri_cd FROM ej6.illes i WHERE c.ilcen_cd = i.ilcen_cd);